# Python implementation of LDA topic model with Gibbs sampling and burnin + thin options?

Tags: python, r, lda, topic-modeling

I am trying to optimize an LDA topic model using collapsed Gibbs sampling. I have been using the `ldatuning` package in R to optimize the number of topics k:

```
controls_tm <- list(
  burnin = 1000,
  iter = 4000,
  thin = 500,
  nstart = 5,
  seed = 0:4,
  best = TRUE
)

   num_cores <- max(parallel::detectCores() - 1, 1)

   result <- FindTopicsNumber(my_dfm, topics = seq(40, 100, by = 5), metrics = c("Griffiths2004", "CaoJuan2009", "Arun2010", "Deveaud2014"), mc.cores = num_cores, control = controls_tm, verbose = TRUE)
```

This is all fine. Now I can run `topicmodels` in R for a given k with the same controls but it takes ~8 hours to run per model, even on a HPC cluster with 27 cores. I am looking for Python implementations of LDA topic models that I can run with the same controls so that it is consistent with what I used to optimize `ldatuning`, but faster, because I need to run multiple models to compare perplexity.

I have looked at the `lda` library in Python which uses Gibbs and takes <1 hour per model. But as far as I can tell, I cannot pass it the burnin or thin parameters.

I have also looked at `sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation` but it uses variational Bayes instead of Gibbs and it also doesn't look like it accepts burnin or thin anyway. Same goes for `gensim` (I think -- I am not very familiar with it).

Does this just not exist in Python? Or is there a workaround so that I can run a model in Python with Gibbs sampling and the parameters I want? Thanks!

Comment: Are yor sure that there is no a parameter like `method="Gibss"`in Python?

Comment: @HenryNavarro I don't think so but I find it strange that the method cannot be chosen in Python. I thought maybe I'm missing something. http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you won't use online training, have you checked gensim's [Latent Dirichlet Allocation via Mallet](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamallet.html)?

> This module allows both LDA model estimation from a training corpus and inference of topic distribution on new, unseen documents, using an (optimized version of) collapsed gibbs sampling from MALLET.